# I am trying to upload an image to firebase using android studio but its not working, what is wrong with my code?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I have not use authentication yet, in the screen i can see the progress dialog working but its not getting stop. I think there is a problem.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(requestCode==GALLERY_INTENT&&resultCode==RESULT_OK){

    progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading Image...");
    progressDialog.show();

    Uri uri = data.getData();
    StorageReference filepath = mStorageRef;
    filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
            progressDialog.dismiss();
            Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Uploading Finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}
```

}

//firebase storage rule

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/csapplication-b6e5e.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth == null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because of if your file upload to firebase was successful means your ProgressDialog will be dismissed ,if not in the case of failure you have to dismiss (ProgressDialog) in the OnFailure method in the code below .

```
 filepath.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
        progressDialog.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Uploading Finished",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
@Override
public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
    // Handle unsuccessful uploads - Dismiss the ProgressDialog here
    progressDialog.dismiss();
    Toast.makeText(Profile.this, "Unable to Uploaded Error in Firebase",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}});
```